# Can an object like node update itself without any need of giving it an updated value?

Tags: java, eclipse, linked-list, nodes, singly-linked-list

(In the insert method): In the else statement, I don't understand how "front.next" is getting updated with the line: "prev.next = newNode". Theoretically, I understand it, but practically, although "prev" gets its value from "curr", which got its value from "front" itself, there is no way that front is getting updated because "prev". How are they talking to each other?

(Insert method)I have tried debugging and when it reaches the else statement that executes => prev.next = newNode; front.next gets updated as well which I just don't understand since front is nowhere being initialised again. Front is an object of itself.

```
public class SinglyLinkedList<T>
{
// inner class being created:
protected class Node<T extends Comparable<T>>
{
    T val;
    Node<T> next;

    Node(T val)
    {
        this.val = val;
        this.next = null;
    }

    Node(T val, Node n)
    {
        this.val = val;
        this.next = n;
    }
}

private Node front, tail;

public SinglyLinkedList()
{
    this.front = this.tail = null;
}

// print method:
public void print()
{
    // print the contents of the list
    Node curr = front;
    while (curr != null)
    {
        System.out.println(curr.val + " ");
        curr = curr.next;
    }
}
// insert method:
public void insert(T val)
{
    Node newNode = new Node((Comparable) val);
    // make a new node
    if (front == null)
    {
        // empty list
        front = tail = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        // list is not empty
        Node curr = front, prev = null;
        // look for insert point.
        while (curr != null && curr.val.compareTo(val) < 0)
        {
            prev = curr;
            curr = curr.next;
        }
        // insert node before curr
        newNode.next = curr;
        if (curr == front)
        {
            // update front
            front = newNode;
        }
        else
        {
            // update node before
            prev.next = newNode;
        }
        if (tail.next != null)
        {
            // move tail to last node
            tail = tail.next;
        }
    }
}
```

}

I expected curr to keep continuing to fill in the chain of nodes using curr.next and using "prev" as a temporary node used in the process of adding a node in between two nodes.

I also didn't expect print method to work since it begins with front node. Theoretically, it does make sense to start with front node, but looking at my code how "front" is not equalling to any value, but rather "curr" equalling "front", makes me feel that "front" shouldn't be having the access to the rest chain of nodes.

I expected "front.next" to be null, but it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Well, according to your code, the `front` works as the first node of the linked list, it actually equals to a certain value (a real node) because your code set it to be so a

```java
if (front == null)
{
    // empty list
    front = tail = newNode;
}
```

and

```java
if (curr == front)
{
    // update front
    front = newNode;
}
```

See! You indeed pointed it to a certain node with a given value.

For the update question. I think possibly you are always inserting a new node right next to the front node. Under that circumstance, the `prev` points to the same node as the `front` do. So if you update `prev`, you are updating `front`, too!

Comment: There is one certain case though where it doesn't go in the if statement and skips to else statement. There is a certain case when it never gets into the else statement! I really appreciate you for getting back on this.